# Photoshop print to postscript outputs incorrectly as 8.5X11

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow

Our normal workflow with CS5 was printing the `.psd` to `.ps` (postscript), and then processing the `.ps` with Distiller to `.pdf`.

Under CS6, I don't know if it's me or the version I am using, but all `.psd` files print to `.ps` as 8.5x11.   The `Print Settings` `Position and Size` attributes are as followed: `Scale: 100%, Height: 12" Width 15".`

From the `Printer Setup` section of the `Print Settings` dialog, I click `Print Settings`, to display the `Print` dialog, verify that `Paper Size` is set to `Width 15 Height 12`.  I select `Save as Postscript`, specify a filename and location,  then click `Save` to return to the `Print Settings` dialog, and verify that the preview is labeled `15" x 12"` and correctly displays the whole image, then click `Print` to create the file.

The file is created, but opening in Preview (or processing it in Distiller) shows what appears to be an 8.5 X 11 crop of the original.

I've done this on several projects before, am I overlooking something?

Comment: Probably just the PDF viewing application placing it on a letter sized sheet, with auto-scaling disabled. Set the paper size to custom in the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this by changing the PDF producer used by Adobe from the `Mac OS X ... Quartz` to `Adobe Photoshop for Macintosh -- Image Conversion Plug-in`.   Now from Photoshop, I can simply `Save As` select `Photoshop PDF` as Format, and Standard: [`DF/X-1a:2001`, and `Save PDF`.  I think this is specific to CS6 forward.

The postscript file output is still clipping to 8.5 X 11, but I don't need it, with the Image Conversion Plugin solution.